# Is this a variation of an anonymous inner class?

Tags: java, anonymous-class

Here is an example

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        // do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        // do stuff
    }
};
```

Would this just be a variation of an anonymous inner class, or is it something else entirely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes that is an anonymous inner class

Comment: @Nathan, what does the term "anonymous" mean?

Comment: @mre: it's not given a name: you don't have to say `class MyClass extends JPanel` and then instantiate `MyClass` using its name.

Comment: @mre well you are instantiating a new class that you are defining without a name

Comment: @mre essentially it means that the class is unnamed. What you have here is an anonymous inner class specifically: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html

Comment: @Bruno, @Nathan, thanks. to me, the term is confusing, especially when it doesn't appear "anonymous" to me. :)

Answer (score 5):

You may be confused about the anonymity of the class because at first blush it looks like you're defining panel to be an instance of JPanel.  However, that's not what you are doing.  Instead you are defining a *sub-class* of JPanel, which is a new class and creating panel to be an instance of this new sub-class.  What is the name of this new class?  Well, it doesn't have one and hence that's what makes it anonymous!

Answer (score 1):

That is an anonymous inner class.