# Unable to understand declaration

Tags: java

I have a code snippet as

```
public class ThreadStates {
    private static Thread t1 = new Thread("T1") {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(2);
                for (int i = 100; i > 0; i--) ;
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.......And rest of code follows.

What type of declation is step 1. I can see that we have no inherited Thread class in ThreadStates class, then why run() method declaration is coming.  PLease clarify what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created an anonymous inner class which inherits from `Thread` (note the `{` directly following `new Thread()`. You are giving this class a run method, and storing it in t1.

Answer (score 3):

It's called an anonymous inner class.  When you say 'new Thread("T1") { ... }', you're effectively defining a new subclass of Thread.

[Is this a variation of an anonymous inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432545/is-this-a-variation-of-an-anonymous-inner-class)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

When you call a class that directly implements the `Runnable` class, you immediately inherit all the methods that said class does. `Thread` is one of the classes that implements `Runnable` and it makes you implement the `run()`method which is an abstract one.

That's why it shows the `run()`nethod there.